# Using ISNULL when adding NULL to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whilst experimenting with MSSQL I came across some behaviour I cannot explain.

I was looking at what happens to a NULL value when it is added to a varchar, and when I do the following query:

```
SELECT
   ISNULL(NULL + ' ', 'test')
```

I get the result 'te'. Similarly if I change the word test for any other word I only get the first two letters. If I increase the number of spaces in the + ' ' I get extra letters in my result (so NULL + '[two spaces]' gives me 'tes'). Any ideas what is going on?

If I declare a variable and set it to NULL e.g.

```
DECLARE @testnull AS varchar(32)

SET @testnull = NULL

SELECT
ISNULL(@testnull + ' ', 'test')
```

then I get the result 'test' (as I would expect).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `COALESCE`. `ISNULL` takes the *first* NON-NULL data type, and in this case because it hasn't been declared, you get a `VARCHAR(1)` for the `NULL` and then it becomes a `VARCHAR(2)` when you add the space (this is still `NULL` when evaluated but SQL Server makes an assumption before that step). In some cases the default for `varchar` without length is 1, and in others it is 30. I'll let you guess which one is being used here.

```
SELECT
 ISNULL(NULL + ' ', 'test'), COALESCE(NULL + ' ', 'test');
```

Results:

```
----  ----
te    test
```

You can see this explicitly by:

```
SELECT
   x = ISNULL(NULL + ' ', 'test')
   INTO #a1;

SELECT
   x = COALESCE(NULL + ' ', 'test')
   INTO #a2;

SELECT LEFT(t.name, 3), TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id), max_length
FROM tempdb.sys.columns AS c
  INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.tables AS t
  ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
  WHERE t.name LIKE '#a[1-2]%';
```

Results:

```
---  -------  ----
#a1  varchar     2
#a2  varchar     4
```

In almost all cases, I prefer `COALESCE` over `ISNULL`. I explain why (and where the exceptions exist) in this tip:

- [Deciding between COALESCE and ISNULL in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: How come `varchar(1)` gets `'te'`?

Comment: @Kaf It becomes varchar(2) when you add `' '`.

Comment: My friend, you don't cease to amaze me in this niche, +1 for a fantastic answer!

Comment: Great answer, and really useful article too. Thanks!

Comment: I can see a pattern how it happens [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10861), but it gives full string for `null + null`.

Comment: @Kaf `ISNULL` takes the first ***NON-NULL*** data type it finds. `NULL+NULL` does not fit that bill, so it moves on to the string. With `NULL+' '` it makes a slightly more logical assumption based on the literal.